# Positioning in Xamarin Forms with Repeater, Relative view and scroll

Tags: xamarin, layout, xamarin.forms, scroll, repeater

I have a problem to setup a proper layout for Xamarin Forms

I need to have a layout in which buttons are generated by Repeater. The area must be scrollable so that only 3 buttons are visible at the moment with the height of Repeater/3, and they are filling the whole area, rest will be scrolled. All buttons need to have the same height (Repeater/3). I dont know the number of buttons

I have something like this

```
        <ScrollView  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Column="1" BackgroundColor="Red">
        <RelativeLayout x:Name="XName">
            <controls:RepeaterView ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}" x:Name="Test"  
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}">
                <controls:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <RelativeLayout 
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=Test Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}">
                                <Button Text="{Binding Name}"  RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"/>
                            </RelativeLayout>
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </controls:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
            </controls:RepeaterView>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

My code produces sth like this:

[image]

I need something like this:

[image]

The content of image is not important. I need to have the buttons scaled so that 3 buttons will will all red area, rest (of the same size) will be scorlled

Answer (score 0):

Don't let the `ScrollView` "FillAndExpand" vertically. Instead, give it `HeightRequest` of 3 buttons + padding or put the `ScrollView` in little container 3 buttons tall.
Also you can put it in `Grid` like this:

```
<Grid>
   <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="3*" />
      <RowDefinition Height="7*" />
   </Grid.RowDefinitions>
   <ScrollView  HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Grid.Row="0" BackgroundColor="Red">
        <controls:RepeaterView ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}" x:Name="Test">
            <controls:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <RelativeLayout 
                            HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToView,ElementName=Test Property=Height,Factor=1,Constant=0}">
                            <Button Text="{Binding Name}"  RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1,Constant=0}"/>
                        </RelativeLayout>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </controls:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
        </controls:RepeaterView>
   </ScrollView>
</Grid>
```

So that first row will fill 3/10 (0.3 or 30%) of the screen and second row will fill 7/10 of the screen.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. The height of 3 buttons means to fill the whole red area (I would like buttons to be higher then in my picture). I would prefer not to use any absolute dimensions, and keep it scalable. The scroolview is already located in a grid area that covers the desired height of 3 buttons. The problem is that repeater generates it in a different way and puts 5-6 buttons in the area.

Comment: Where to put the grid ? Should it be treated as repeter item or as a container ? Sorry for such stupid questions but i am new to Xamarin and it really annoys me ;)

Comment: Your code in this case only reduces the height of whole red area to 1/3. I need one button to have the area of 1/3 of red field, but the whole red field must remain unchanged - 3 buttons must be located there.

Comment: I don't understand what do you want. If you want 3 button in an area - make this area height be 3 buttons tall. If you want an area to be scalable with size of screen - put this area in a grid with rowdefinitions as above. Or mb you want to scale button height with size of container that scales with size of screen?

Comment: OK let me explain it once again. The red area is of fixed size dependant on other controls sizes. In the red area, I would like to have the unknown number of buttons, but I want each of those buttons to be the size of ~1/3 of the whole red area (~because of margins paddings etc). If there will be less than 3 buttons they won't fill the whole area  If there will be more than 3 they should be scrolled but in any case each button must be of 1.3 of the red area.

Answer (score 0):

OK I have managed to partially do what I intended:

```
            <ScrollView Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
            <RelativeLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="Green">
                <controls:RepeaterView ItemsSource="{Binding Buttons}" x:Name="Test"
                 VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                 RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=2}"
                RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1}">
                    <controls:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ViewCell>
                                <Button  Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
                            </ViewCell>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </controls:RepeaterView.ItemTemplate>
                </controls:RepeaterView>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that scrollview does not display all elementst, but only 3.

Comment: The problem is that scrollview does not display all elementst, but only 3. Good. This is exactly what you was asking for.